# How to grant certain apps root permission through ADB?

Tags: applications, adb, root-access

I have an Android TV box (4.4.2, armv7), and I can login the device as root by ADB (local network). What I want to do is to give certain apps root permission. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't *give certain apps root permission*, but *certain apps ask for root permission* by executing `su` binary. It's the developer of the app who decides if the app would perform some tasks with root privileges or not. In order to let apps request root privileges, you need *to root* your device using e.g. Magisk, SuperSU etc. (whatever works on your device).

When you get root privileges on `adb` (e.g. by executing `adb root` or `adb shell su`) it runs `adbd` process on device as root (UID `0`) user. So all commands which you run through `adb` have root privileges. To grant root access to apps you need a ***special `su` binary*** which is not shipped with Android.

The usual `su` binary (like on any UNIX-like OS) makes a transition to UID `0` by making `setuid` syscall to kernel. This is not possible on Android due to certain restrictions. The special `su` binary (the one provided by rooting solutions like Magisk) connects to a background daemon to get a root shell for the requesting app, where the app can execute commands with root privileges. However the app itself is still running with its own UID (assigned at the time of installation).

For more details see:

- [What special privileges “/system/xbin/su” does have w.r.t. root access?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207902/218526)
- [How Magisk works?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213344/218526)
- [How to manually root a phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217157/218526)

Comment: Thanks for ans, and I found there is a file named `su` which's location is `/system/xbin` and I run `chmod 777` to this file. Then I install supersu on the box but it remind "su binary occupied". So do I have a solution to solve it?

Comment: @punnpkin you need to root your device, using e.g. Magisk or SuperSU. The `su` binary already provided in Android cannot be used with SuperSU. They provide their own `su` binaries. That's what I tried to explain in the answer. For more details see linked answers.

Comment: OK, I learned it, Actually, I'm just looking for a way to root my device without changing the rom. (Because it has some customized content.)

Comment: I don't understand this answer. If you can `adb root` and you run have root privs, why can't you run the app? That doesn't make sense, you grant root access to anything root runs. Why can't someone with root access run an android app?

Comment: @EvanCarroll because Android apps cannot make use of SUID bit. Please read “How Android restricts root access?” in the linked answers.